# How to create a bag of word in Python

Tags: python, nltk

Dataframe **test** after I cleaned and tokenized it.

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
tt = TweetTokenizer()
test['tokenize'] = test['tweet'].apply(tt.tokenize)
print(test)
```

output

```
0  congratulations dear friend ... [congratulations, dear, friend]
1  happy anniversary be happy  ... [happy, anniversary, be, happy]
2  make some sandwich          ...          [make, some, sandwich]
```

I would like to create a bag of word for my data. The following gave me error: *'list' object has no attribute 'lower'*

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

BOW = vectorizer.fit_transform(test['tokenize'])
print(BOW.toarray())
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

The second one: *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'*

```
from collections import Counter
test['BOW'] = test['tokenize'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(" ")))
print(test['BOW'])
```

Can you please assist me either method or both. Thanks!

Comment: As follows from your output example, the _test['tokenize']_ contains lists in cells. Those lists are values retrieved from string by splitting by " ", so to get this line `test['BOW'] = test['tokenize'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(" ")))` working, try to change it into `test['BOW'] = test['tokenize'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x))`

Comment: It worked out well, thanks!

Comment: I've moved my comment to answer

Comment: I will appreciate if someone can help me figure out what I got wrong with the first method. The one with 'from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer'... thank you

Comment: Could you provide stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vectorizer.fit_transform` takes an iterable of str, unicode, or file objects as a parameter. You have passed an iterable of lists (of tokenized strings). You can just pass the original set of strings, `test['tweet']` as CountVectorizer does the tokenizing for you.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
BOW = vectorizer.fit_transform(test['tweet'])
print(BOW.toarray())
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

This should give you your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As follows from your output example, the *test['tokenize']* contains lists in cells. Those lists are values retrieved from string by splitting by " ", so to get this line `test['BOW'] = test['tokenize'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(" ")))` working, try to change it into `test['BOW'] = test['tokenize'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x))`